# Please tell me can I be forgiven

Tags: tawba

1- I had watched porn 2- I SEXTED and got received a nude when I was 12 3- when I was 13 I used to always thing sexualy to every girl 4- I stole card(toy) when I was 8. 5- I fear I did sheirk as a kid

Comment: Please stop repeating the same questions over and over. Consider googling your questions first.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a repeated post.
Anyway, haven't you heard the story of the one who was forgiven even after killing a hundred people!

Allah (swt) forgives all sins as long as one repents.